# VBA Access Table reference in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have been running into trouble executing SQL code in VBA Access when I refer to certain Table names.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (ClientName) SELECT DISTINCT 1_1_xlsx.ClientName FROM 1_1_xlsx'<--does not work
```

The code works fine when I changed the Table name from `1_1_xlsx` to `Stuff`.

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (ClientName) SELECT DISTINCT Stuff.ClientName FROM Stuff '<--works
```

I have no idea why the first query results in a syntax error and the second code is runs fine even when they refer to the same thing. I suspect it should be the naming conventions but I could not find any concrete answers.

Also, are there any ways that I could use `1_1_xlsx` as my table name? Or am I just writing my query wrong?

Comment: If you have trouble with names, always start by bracketing them (`[1_1_xlsx]`)

Comment: Could be that _xslx_ confuses the SQL parser to believe that this about some linked Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (ClientName) SELECT DISTINCT [1_1_xlsx].ClientName FROM [1_1_xlsx]
```

Answer (score 0):

In many SQL based databases you can't have a table name or field name that starts with a number.

I suspect this is the underlying reason for your problem. Although Access will allow it, I have seen it cause problems in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the number at the beginning of the table name.  That is bad -- because it confuses the parser.

This is a bad table name, but SQL allows you to define table aliases.  And, in this case, you don't even need to repeat the table name.  So, here are two simple solutions:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (ClientName)
    SELECT DISTINCT ClientName
    FROM 1_1_xlsx;
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable (ClientName)
    SELECT DISTINCT t.ClientName
    FROM 1_1_xlsx as t
```

There is no reason to use the complete table name as an alias.  That just makes the query harder to write and to read.